# YouTube video not autoplaying when dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

Alright so I am having some issues with iframes, it simply wont autoplay no matter how I set it up.

Heres the code snippet that I'm using to append it

```
$('.gallery').html("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='"+genDetails[i]['video_url']+"?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
```

If I open this URL in my browser it will autoplay itself and everything works as it's supposted to but whenever I add it onto my page using HTML it simply wont autoplay...

Comment: What does the rendered URL look like in the src attribute?

Comment: For example something like this https://www.youtube.com/embed/6Ejga4kJUts (of course Htttps and all the stuff infront of it just stack cuts it off when posting). Its the URL from embeed option

Comment: What does the query string end up looking like?